# A tag base afeta scripts e estilos num documento html?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, html-tags

Tendo em `http://exemplo.com/diretorio1/documento1.html` o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Uma página</title>
        <base href="http://exemplo.com/diretorio2/" />
        <script>
            function foo(){
                window.location.href= "documento2.html";
            }
            // Mais Scripts...
        </script>
        <style>
            @import url("estilo2.css");
            /* Estilos etc... */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

A função `foo` de 
`<script>`consegue seguir até `http://exemplo.com/diretorio2/documento2.html`?

O estilo em `<style>` consegue importar o arquivo `http://exemplo.com/diretorio2/estilo2.css`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, exato, todos os URLs relativos do documento.

A [descrição da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

> [...] specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document [...]
>
> **Traduzido:** especifica a base do URL para usar em todos os URLs relativos do documento.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/4q2fpyft/
<sub>(onde uso o base para o url de uma imagem e para o CSS)</sub>:

```
<base href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css?v=4da5848172aa">
<div class="topbar">
    [...]
</div>
<img src="img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b" alt="" />
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]